# Custom ViewGroup (compound view) onMeasure and onLayout calls in ViewPager

Tags: android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, android

I have developed custom compound view which extends `FrameLayout` and includes several ui elements.

After all children are measured I want so resize some elements and set paddings depending on other element size.

As I understand the right place to do it is `onMeasure` after calling `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);`

1. When app opens for first time or is minimized and reopened I see following calls in log:

`onMeasure
onMeasure
onLayout
onMeasure
onLayout`

It's working fine. After layout changed it measures everything one more time.

But after swiping pages in ViewPager I return to the fragment containing this view only

`onMeasure
onLayout`

are called. So resizing and padding is not set to some elements.

Why `onMeasure` is not called after `onLayout` in this case? Where I need to resize and set padding of my views if I know needed sizes only after other elements are measured?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I have found a solution. Not sure how good it is.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // views are measured. so needed views can be resized depending on other views
    resizeNeededViews()

    // measure everything another one time
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```